# Configure Kafka Connect to source data from MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jdbc

I am using [Kafka connect: connecting JDBC source using Mysql](http://www.infoobjects.com/kafka-connect-connecting-jdbc-source-using-mysql/) to source data using Kafka Connect for a Kafka stream but instead of MySQL using Microsoft SQL Server on a Ubuntu 14 virtual machine within Virtual Box.

The Kafka server is in Virtual Box connecting through to my workstation that has the MSSQL Server instance and the connectivity between the two machine is working because Kafka is connecting and authenticating against MSSQL however there is a Kafka commit issue on the autoincrement topic.

My Kafka Connect configuration is as follows to connect to the [xd] database and change data capture the data01 table using the id column.

```
name=test-mssql-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;user=xd;password=xd;databaseName=scratchpad
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id
topic.prefix=test-mssql-jdbc-
table.whitelist=data01
```

My table schema is as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE [xd].[data01](
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[surname] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

However I am getting the error from Kafka that it is unable to flush the autoincrement queue.

```
[2016-09-09 11:09:07,452] ERROR Failed to flush WorkerSourceTask{id=test-mssql-jdbc-autoincrement-0}, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 1 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:289)
[2016-09-09 11:09:07,453] ERROR Failed to commit offsets for WorkerSourceTask{id=test-mssql-jdbc-autoincrement-0} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter:109)
[2016-09-09 11:10:12,454] ERROR Failed to flush WorkerSourceTask{id=test-mssql-jdbc-autoincrement-0}, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 1 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:289)
[2016-09-09 11:10:12,455] ERROR Failed to commit offsets for WorkerSourceTask{id=test-mssql-jdbc-autoincrement-0} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter:109)
```